# Disable Wi-Fi on GA-F2A88XN-WIFI motherboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, power-management

I'd like to disable the wi-fi hardware (and maybe also bluetooth) on my Gigabyte GA-F2A88XN-WIFI, for power saving purposes. I did not see an option in the BIOS.

On the software side, I've already told the OS (fedora) not to look for wireless connections:
[image: Network manager with wireless unchecked]

Yes, I know it sounds silly with a motherboard that has *WIFI* in its very name, but that's not what I bought it for: it's a mini-ITX A88X mobo with few competitors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it does much, but I installed `powertop` (the package is available in Fedora repositories), typed `sudo powertop`, tabbed to "Tunables" and switched one wifi setting from "Bad" to "Good" by pressing enter ("Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Wireless 7260"):

[image: Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Wireless 7260]